# Tell vim to add commas to a number, e.g. change 31415926 to 31,415,926

Tags: vim

I have a very large number (a couple hundred digits long), and I'd like to use vim to add commas to the number in the appropriate manner, i.e. after each group of three digits, moving from right to left. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: One possible approach would be to reverse the number, use `:s` to insert a comma after each group of three digits from left to right, and then reverse the number again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/70975)

Substitue command that adds commas in the right spot.

```
:%s/\(\d\)\(\(\d\d\d\)\+\d\@!\)\@=/\1,/g
```

This uses a zero width lookahead to match any number that isn't followed by groups of three numbers followed by one number. (or 3n+1 numbers)

So the numbers that match in are marked with `^`. These are then replaced with a comma after it the match.

```
31415926
 ^  ^
```

Which replaces to

```
31,415,926
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't see why. In 31415926, the first "1" is followed by "4159", which matches the pattern `\(\d\d\d\)\+\d`, so shouldn't the negative lookahead fail to match?

Comment: @TannerL.Swett the plus is greedy (consumes as much as it can) and matches `415` and `926`. Then it checks to see if there is a number after it. Since there isn't the match fails. `\@!` matches only if the pattern DOES NOT match. Therefore the first `1` matches the regex.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine suggests using the printf program: `ciw<C-r>=system("printf \"%'d\" ".shellescape(@"))<CR>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
s/\d\{-1,}\ze\(\d\{3}\)\+\s/&,/g
```

Notes:

- `\{-1,}` is saying match at least 1 but in a non-greedy way (Vim doesn't seem to support the usual `\+\?` syntax; also, for quantifiers, you just need to escape the opening curly brace)
- `\ze` is saying match the pattern behind this but don't store the match in `&` (equivalent to positive look-ahead)
- `\(\d\{3}\)\+\>` matches groups of 3 digits that ends with word-nonword boundary (word in this sense means alphanumerical + underscore).

  - Alternatively, you can use `\s` for space/tab, or `\D` for non-digit instead of `\>`, whichever fits your needs better

Comment: Instead of the `\s` I think using `\>` (end of word) would be better.

Comment: @FDinoff, Yeah, I've been juggling between `\s`, `\D`, or `\>`. I think I'll just mention all of 'em.

Comment: As a side note vim's non-greedy modifier is `\{-}` see `:h non-greedy`

Comment: @FDinoff, Hm, but `\{-}` seems to correspond to Perl regex's `*?` though, is there a nicer way to write Perl regex's `+?` other than `\{-1,}`?

Comment: I do not think so. Look at `:h perl-patterns`.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I used is to create a macro that adds one single comma, and then invoke the macro a whole bunch of times, like `qahhi,<ESC>hq@a@a@a@a`…